# Instagram API Endpoint: GET /locations/search Distance Parameter

Tags: api, parameters, location, instagram, endpoint

I am currently using the locations/search endpoint of the Instagram API using a python script to recieve one single location name for specific coordinate pairs (lat, lng). 
To only get the most matching location back, I tried to implement the *distance*
parameter and set it to 0 (also tried 1 etc. - played around with it).
My get request currently looks like this:

`{base}locations/search?lat={latitude}&lng={longitude}&distance={dist}&access_token={token}'.format(base="https://api.instagram.com/v1/".....)`

I used the Instagram Developer Documentation as reference.
(https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/locations/)

But what ever I input as distance parameter, the output is always the same. Meaning I always get multiple locations back. As I mentioned above, I played around with it - it seemes like there is no effect what so ever.

I would be grateful I somebody could help me out and tell me what i did wrong.
Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

This is not a direct answer to the question, but for whoever ends up on this question - this endpoint does no longer exist.